# What do those "You've won an iPad" Javascript popups at scummy web sites actually do?

Tags: javascript, security

(This might be better asked over at SuperUser, but I'm interested in the vulnerabilities of the Javascript alert box, and what the code might actually be doing, not the effect on my computer.)

We've all gotten these popup boxes with just an OK button and nothing else. I usually close them without hitting OK and go back to safety.

Is hitting OK any worse than just closing the window? What exploit, if any, are these popups trying to use?

Comment: Just a way to spam you with advertising trying to get you to buy into free gift cards.  In life nothing is free.

Comment: Can you give a picture of what you are talking about? It sounds like just normal JavaScript alert boxes, in which case clicking ok is no different than closing the alert box.  Said alert boxes are probably just being used to keep you on the site as long as possible.

Comment: The best exploit of all: "Gullibility" - currently incurable. They're the exactly the same as the "You're our 1,000,000th visitor!" , just like every other visitor.

Answer (score 1):

I would refer to that type of exploit as [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking)

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of exploits that involve putting an image on top of some other control (e.g. a Flash button) and convincing you to click, but registering the click to the hidden control.

At worst, this can mean you are permitting a local installation, etc., allowing the site to have control of your machine.

There was an entertaining one discovered recently in which a malicious site could actually convince you to share control of your webcam (by clicking on a hidden Flash control), allowing them to take pictures of you.